# How to use more than 1 set of rules in extends in eslint yaml file?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, eslint

If I have

```
env:
  commonjs: true
  es6: true
  node: true
extends:
- plugin:mocha/recommended
...
```

I get no error, i.e. linting passes with

```
eslint .
```

but if I try and add in `eslint:recommended` in addition to the mocha one, i.e.

```
env:
  commonjs: true
  es6: true
  node: true
extends:
- eslint:recommended
- plugin:mocha/recommended
...
```

I get loads of errors as the mocha one isn't applied

```
71:3   error  'it' is not defined          no-undef  <-- from the mocha tests
```

How can I have both recommendations in a yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with using a YAML file, and the Mocha plugin *is* being applied in both cases. The first linting passes because, without `eslint:recommended`, **the rule [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) is not enabled**. For example, given the following basic setup:

```
temp/
  node_modules/
  .eslintrc.yml
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  test.js
```

Where `test.js` contains:

```js
describe("something",function () {
  it("should pass linting", function () {});
});
```

and `.eslintrc.yml` contains:

```yml
extends:
- plugin:mocha/recommended
```

then linting passes. But if I just add that one rule:

```yml
extends:
- plugin:mocha/recommended
rules:
  no-undef: error
```

then linting fails with:

```
path/to/temp/test.js
  1:1  error  'describe' is not defined  no-undef
  2:3  error  'it' is not defined        no-undef

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

Per [the configuration docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments), you need to set the *environment* for the globals to be defined; for example, the following configuration is back to passing:

```yml
env:
  mocha: true
extends:
- plugin:mocha/recommended
rules:
  no-undef: error
```

Now you can enable the full suite of recommended rules and still pass linting:

```yml
env:
  mocha: true
extends:
- eslint:recommended
- plugin:mocha/recommended
```